# Check if a Javascript variable is used in any if statement

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, syntax, global-variables

I want to check whether a given Javascript variable goes is used by any IF statements inside the program. Is there a way to dynamically do this rather than pure static code analysis.

Am not reading any file here. Lets say that I can inject a piece of JS code using some extension during run time and dynamically find if a given variable goes through an IF statement.

Comment: Are you reading a javascript file, then?

Comment: Or are you making one and want to test it?

Comment: Would this include `var b = a; if (b){...}`? (indirect usage of `a`)

Comment: That would be great. But I would be happy to start with direct ones. Like, if(a){...}

Comment: @Skeptical: then create a parser that finds every conditional statement, creates a hashset of the variables being used within those conditions, then perform the look-up on that hashset.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? Letting the program run and being notified when the variable is accessed? Every decent debugger should be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea. There are lots of things that could go wrong. You could look into [sandboxing](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/).

But, as long as you aren't relying on this for security, you might find this useful:

```
var x = function (a, b, c) { if(a) {console.log(a)}};
var y = function (a, b, c) { if(b) {console.log(a)}};

// You can get the text of a function. Notice it's been formatted.
console.log(x.toString());
>>> "function (a, b, c) { if (a) { console.log(a) } }"

var matcher = /if ?\(.?a.?\)/g;

x.toString().match(matcher);
>>> ["if (a)"]

y.toString().match(matcher);
>>> null
```

Things to be careful of, off the top of my head:

- Different browsers may format the code differently.
- Variables can be aliased by assigning them to a different name.
- Variables can be accessed by index-access and strings.
- This is a naïve regular expression and will obviously match `if (nota)`.
- Your javascript will be visible, so anyone who wants to get round this will find a way.

Comment: Another alternative to iframe sandboxing would be a capability processor like Caja http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caja_project